# Cost for retrieving user data using Firebase Admin Auth

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I came across the following cloud function which gets all users data. What would it cost me transaction wise?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

const auth = admin.auth();

/**
 * Gets all the users (1000 MAX) from Firebase auth.
 *
 * @param {Object} req Express Request Object.
 * @param {Object} res Express Response Object
 */
const getAllUsers = (req, res) => {
  const maxResults = 1; // optional arg.

  auth.listUsers(maxResults).then((userRecords) => {
    userRecords.users.forEach((user) => console.log(user.toJSON()));
    res.end('Retrieved users list successfully.');
  }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
};

module.exports = {
  api: functions.https.onRequest(getAllUsers),
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am concerned, there is absolutely no cost connected to this.
This is probably also the reason for the limit of `1000` users.
*Firebase Authentication* does not  store a lot of data and is not meant to be used as a "database". Hence, it would not make sense to bill "user" reads.
You could also just sit there all day and refresh the `Users` tab in the Firebase Console and it would also not cost you anything.

You will probably get rate limited if you try to fetch users too often.
For any other concerns, you should contact Firebase support.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Authentication is for the most part a free product. The only paid part is phone number verification, which you're not using in this code. There's no cost associated with listing users using the Admin SDK.